# How to get the inertia at the begining when using sklearn.cluster.KMeans and MiniBatchKMeans

Tags: scikit-learn, k-means, model-evaluations

When I cluster a lot of data, it is hard to run KMeans and wait it stop until centers has not change, so I have to stop KMeans when it reach maximum number of iterations. 
Here come problem: how can I evaluate the impact of this KMeans did for my data. I know I can get [the inertia_ after KMeans fitting](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html) my data to see the sum of distances of samples to their closest cluster center. But How can I get the the inertia_ before KMeans fitting with which I can compare it with the the inertia_ after KMeans fitting, so that I can see the improvement of KMeans did for my data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are grappling with large data set sizes, for which I first suggest switching to [`mini-batch k-means`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.MiniBatchKMeans.html#sklearn.cluster.MiniBatchKMeans). Mini-batch scales better so will be less frustrating.

Regarding apriori estimates of the `inertia_`, I suggest using a sample data set to approximate the `inertia_` with appropriate margins of error. But, mini-batch may just preclude your need for apriori `inertia_`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! But a little confused about "using a sample data set to approximate the inertia_ with appropriate margins of error". Do you mean that randomly sample from data, and compute inertia_ manually when I set initial centers. Then compute inertia_ when MiniBatchKMeans finished?